# Find Maximum money you can make by making at most 2 transactions(find the two largest non-overlapping increases in a list)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Note: no overlap, the second buy should be later than first sell.

Given a stream of quotes for a stock from the last trading day. Assume its already time sorted. Find the maximum amount of money you could have made on this stock by making  2 transactions. A buy and a sell is counted as one transaction.

Example:

```
time Price 
1 10 
2 11 
3 7 
4 15 
5 8 
6 17 
7 16
```

answer is 8 + 9 buy at 3, sell at 4, buy at 5, sell at 6.

Comment: seriously? there are better answers that that. Are there some hidden rules you forgot to include in your question (e.g. can the trades overlap; do I get to re-invest money I make in previous trades or not; have I got infinite seed money; can I short sell)?

Comment: is it me or buying at 7(4) sell at 8(15) then buy at 9(5) sell at 12(17) give a much better +value? 8+12 = 20

Comment: @icfseth I have re-formatted; it may make more sense now

Comment: So I can't buy at 3 twice, then sell at 6 twice?

Comment: So basically what you really want is "find the two largest non-overlapping increases in a list"?

Comment: why can't I buy at 1(price 10) and sell at 2(price 11)? This will add 1 to the profit.

Comment: Are you asking for clever answers?  For every combination of 4 unique points, you could calculate the profit from a buy/sell/buy/sell at those points.  Now you know how much you could make in every scenario, including the scenario that profits the most.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic programming

d[i][j].b = income after i-th time, having made j transactions, j-th transaction only buy
d[i][j].s = income after i-th time, having made j transactions, j-th transaction bought and sold
base d[i][j].b = d[i][j].v = -inf; d[0][0].s = 0;

in this particular case j is 1-2 only

```
d[i][j].b = max(d[i-1][j-1].s - price[i], d[i-1][j].b)
d[i][j].s = max(d[i-1][j].b + price[i], d[i-1][j].s)
```

something like this

O(n*k) where k - number of transactions, so O(n) in this case